# how to keep all data of column in one line together in csv

Tags: linux, perl, csv, awk

I have a csv file which has 2 columns id, notetext.  In second column (notetext), data comes in multiple lines.  What I want is to bring all data in one line.

Here is sample:

```
**catalog_SID, Note_Text**
584,"Sample in a Glove Bag only.  Refer to SOP
489-701 for sampling
great
procedure."
647,"Do not use
hotplate"
680,Sample in a Glove Bag
```

What I need is all data in notetext in one line like these:

```
**catalog_SID, Note_Text**
584,"Sample in a Glove Bag only.Refer to SOP 489-701 for sampling."
647,"Do not use hotplate"
680,Sample in a Glove Bag
```

Any idea how to accomplish this?

Comment: how do you differentiate between a newline in your token and a newline that ends the set of tokens?

Comment: @Constantin: I think it's fair to assume that the data may not include newlines

Comment: Your expected output doesn't match you sample input. Where did the spaces before `Refer` go? Where did `great procedure` go? If you really want a tool that makes those changes then explain how it'd know to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Just read the whole file and replace all newlines with spaces if they are not followed by digits and a comma

```
perl -0777 -pe's/\n(?!\d+,)/ /g' myfile
```

#### output

```
catalog_SID, Note_Text
584,"Sample in a Glove Bag only.  Refer to SOP 489-701 for sampling great procedure."
647,"Do not use hotplate"
680,Sample in a Glove Bag
```

Comment: Thanks @Borodin for your answer.But still column in csv contains multiple lines

Comment: @AnimeshSheolikar: Are you working with a file from a Windows system? `s/\R(?!\d+,)/ /g` may help. If not, then please post your data on pastebin.com or similar

Comment: Hi @Boroding : i am sending link for file :

Comment: @AnimeshSheolikar: Yes, you have a Windows file there. Are you running your program on Linux?

Comment: I tried both in linux as well as windows.I am doing it manually to as of now since i did not got any sol.so you can see top few records in one line.

Comment: @AnimeshSheolikar:  It works fine on Windows. Are you **A)** Using double quotes instead of single quotes and **B)** redirecting your output to the new file? It should look like `perl -0777 -pe"s/\n(?!\d+,)/ /g" myfile > newfile`

Comment: yes u r write .Thanks @Borodin.u r my saviour.I cant vote bcoz of my reputation sure i ll do it later.

Comment: @AnimeshSheolikar: I'm glad to help. I don't care much about points, but it's nice to mark a question as having been answered so that others don't come here thinking help is still required

Answer (score 0):

Just keep count of how many quotes have been seen so far and if that number's even put a newline at the end of the current line, otherwise a space char:

```
$ awk '{ORS=( (c+=gsub(/"/,"&"))%2 ? FS : RS )} 1' file
**catalog_SID, Note_Text**
584,"Sample in a Glove Bag only.  Refer to SOP 489-701 for sampling great procedure."
647,"Do not use hotplate"
680,Sample in a Glove Bag
```